# how to get the name of files inside the resource file in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a situation where I have bunch of text file, json files, binary files inside a project . I want to include them as a part of output dll .  However while using these resource files , I want to use them in a following way.

```
// c++ code
    e.g void MyClass::read()
    {
    SomeLibrary::Deserialize("resources/shader.json"); // this is a mere example.
    }
```

I know i can get the handle of these resources files, however I need to use them as described above.